# Reading file that contains description of twitter emojis

Tags: twitter, julia

I'm trying to read a file that contains tweets in each line and convert each character of tweet to an integer. The file can be found  [here](https://github.com/Cyvhee/SemEval2018-Task3/blob/master/datasets/train/SemEval2018-T4-train-taskA.txt)

However, there is something wrong in 28th [line](https://github.com/Cyvhee/SemEval2018-Task3/blob/master/datasets/train/SemEval2018-T4-train-taskA.txt#L28) in that file. When I look at the file, I see that line is as follows:

```
Wish she could have told me herself. @NicoleScherzy #nicolescherzinger
#OneLove #myfav #MyQueen :heavy_black_heart:️:heavy_black_heart:️
```

Furthermore while reading the file, I print out each line when I read it in that case, the line is printed as (Ignore the first two segment for simplification) :

```
Wish she could have told me herself. @NicoleScherzy #nicolescherzinger #OneLove #myfav #MyQueen :heavy_black_heart:️:heavy_black_heart:️
```

Now, If I want to print them character by character I got an error. Here is the code for that and the error I got:

```
x=" Wish she could have told me herself. @NicoleScherzy #nicolescherzinger #OneLove #myfav #MyQueen :heavy_black_heart:️:heavy_black_heart:️"

for i=1:length(x)
  println(x[i])
end

.
.
.
INFO: #
INFO: m
INFO: y
INFO: f
INFO: a
INFO: v
INFO:  
INFO: #
INFO: M
INFO: y
INFO: Q
INFO: u
INFO: e
INFO: e
INFO: n
INFO:  
INFO: :
INFO: h
INFO: e
INFO: a
INFO: v
INFO: y
INFO: _
INFO: b
INFO: l
INFO: a
INFO: c
INFO: k
INFO: _
INFO: h
INFO: e
INFO: a
INFO: r
INFO: t
INFO: :
INFO: ️
ERROR: UnicodeError: invalid character index
 in slow_utf8_next(::Array{UInt8,1}, ::UInt8, ::Int64) at ./strings/string.jl:67
 in next at ./strings/string.jl:96 [inlined]
 in getindex(::String, ::Int64) at ./strings/basic.jl:70
 in macro expansion; at ./REPL[2]:1 [inlined]
 in anonymous at ./<missing>:?
```

What the heck is that ? Why *h* is represented as *h with an bar on top* and whey there is a space just before the error mesage, should be there another `:`

Comment: You might also be interested in this package: https://github.com/JuliaText/TextAnalysis.jl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings and Unicode are complicated everywhere (because human language is complicated) and in Julia. In addition, the implementation would (and should) probably change in the future. As of v0.5 / v0.6 a way to write the loop in the question is

```
for c in x
    println(c)
end
```

And to use indexing, something like:

```
i = 1
while i<=endof(x)
    println(x[i])
    i = nextind(x,i)
end
```

In general you should be familiar with `endof`, `nextind` to write proper string manipulation in Julia as of v0.5 / v0.6. The REPL help and the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/strings/) should cover them.

Comment: Thank you so much the indexing version will work for me. Unfortunately, I still couldn't understand why I see the h of "heavy_black_heart" as normal h in the github or by linux's less command but h with bar when I read the file by julia. Could you explain it too if possible ?

Comment: There is an "invisible" unicode character 0xFE0F (see link https://codepoints.net/U+FE0F for description) between the colons in `heavyblackheart::heavyblackheart`. Essentially it means an emoji should be there. Now there is also an issue of *graphemes* which are multiple Unicode codepoints (read characters) which encode a single symbol. As mentioned in the answer, it is quite complex, but libraries and Official Standard Libraries have solved most of the complexity - and Julia uses some of them.

Comment: my main purpose is to extract emojies in tweets. But in that case such unicode characters makes my job quite difficult. For example, for the tweet given in my question, I want to extract :heavyblackheart: and put it into a dictionary. But because of these invisible characters I couldn't make it. Is there any simple way to do that ? I mean, for a given set of tweets, creating a dictionary that stores emojies in the tweets.

Comment: Haven't done any tweet processing yet, so I'm not sure. But google is your friend here. In fact, the special Unicode 0xFE0F might actually help you, since it might indicate the fact an emoji is there.